# Assigning to local variable in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does mean next peace of code:

```
update dbo.dbr_schem
set @expr=isnull(@expr+' union all ','') 
+'select ' 
+ cast(pozycja as varchar)  + ','
+ cast(schemat as varchar)  + ',' 
+ cast(nardolny as varchar) + ',' 
+ cast(nargorny as varchar) + '' +
          case when warunekSQL<>'' then ' where ' + warunekSQL else '' end
where indeks=@indeks
```

It looks like simple assigning to the local variable but why it use in update statement ?

Comment: I don't know why this would be done in an `update`.  Usually this sort of processing is done using `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there any diffs between `update` and `select` in this case ?

Comment: The `update` *might* incur extra overhead for logging.  It is probably slightly more expensive than a `select`, because it has to lock rows for updates, even if nothing changes

Answer (score 2):

Updating a local variable in an UPDATE is known as the "quirky update". It is something that is typically used when needing to carry a value across rows of an update in scenarios such as a running total. This was more important of a feature prior to the windowing functions introduced in SQL Server 2012. There is a fairly good discussion of it here that has links to various other articles and forums that would be beneficial to read:

[Please can somebody explain how quirky updates work?](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/5150/please-can-somebody-explain-how-quirky-updates-wor.html)

In this particular case it does not appear that it provides any benefit over doing this in a SELECT. This is because there is no field of the table being updated at the same time as the variable is being set. Being able to deal with a real field in addition to a variable is *not* something that can be done in a SELECT statement (i.e. you cannot do `SELECT field1, @variable = @variable + field2 FROM Table`), which is why the quirky update is sometimes quite handy. Hence, this particular usage could be turned into a SELECT with no functional difference as it is just creating a Dynamic SQL string.

The only possible *functional* difference in this particular usage between an `UPDATE` and `SELECT` would *potentially* be the order of the values concatenated into the string. The reason is that the quirky update is ordered by the Clustered Index whereas changing this to a `SELECT`, with no additional changes to add an `ORDER BY`, will have no *guaranteed* order.

In terms of logging, since nothing is being updated in this `UPDATE` statement, nothing is written to the Transaction Log. I have confirmed this by testing the variable-only scenario (i.e. the current question) as well as an `UPDATE` that does have a field specified in the `SET` clause but no rows match the `WHERE` clause. In neither case was anything logged, not even if an explicit transaction was started and committed.

**Please note** that, with respect to locking, if you are using the `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation level, then fewer (and less impacting) locks will be taken when using an `UPDATE` so there should be little difference between it and using a `SELECT` (since no rows are actually being updated here). Otherwise, both the `UPDATE` and `SELECT` appear to take the same number of locks. The difference, though, is that the `UPDATE` takes "Exclusive" locks whereas the `SELECT` only takes "Shared" locks. Since "Shared" locks are less impacting to other processes and allow for more concurrency, given that no actual field in this table is being updated, this query really should be converted to a `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT @expr = ISNULL(@expr + ' union all ', '') 
+'select ' 
+ cast(pozycja AS VARCHAR(50))  + ','
+ cast(schemat AS VARCHAR(50))  + ',' 
+ cast(nardolny AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' 
+ cast(nargorny AS VARCHAR(50)) + '' +
          CASE WHEN warunekSQL<>'' THEN ' where ' + warunekSQL
               ELSE ''
          END
FROM dbo.dbr_schem
WHERE indeks = @indeks;
```

**Please note** that in the query above, I have specified a length/size for the `CAST AS VARCHAR` which is otherwise unspecified in the query in the Question. Variable length datatypes should not be left as unspecified as the default is either 1 or 30 depending on the situation in which it is being done.

Comment: The documentation is rather specific:  "An UPDATE statement always acquires an exclusive (X) lock on the table it modifies," (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).  Do you have a reference that this is bypassed for a quirky update?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have seen it documented on MSDN and will try to find it and post it here. However, what you found still proves my point since the table here isn't being updated since no actual field is specified in the `SET` clause. Had it been `SET @variable = field = expression` then that would be different. And to be clear, this behavior is not specific to the quirky update. I will notify you when I find that documentation.

Comment: . . A table lock would typically take place before any rows are found, at the beginning of the transaction.  That is a nuance, though.  What I'm really curious about is whether SQL Server has special optimizations to support these "quirky updates".  If so, there might be a reason why they are preferred (or at least supported) over `select`.  Personally, I see no reason to use `update` in this context.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am testing now with SQL Profiler so we do not need to rely on interpretation or memory or possibly erroneous documentation. Though I agree that I see no benefit here for UPDATE as compared to SELECT, outside of possibly to force order, but that is highly unlikely / suspicious.

Comment: Interestingly, the locking behavior varies depending on the table schema.  In the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level and a primary key on indeks, I see an exclusive key lock held for the duration of the transaction on the specified key.  However, with a heap, I see update locks acquired *and released*, during the scan.  Quirky indeed.  Personally, I'd use a SELECT for this task.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, so far I have been testing on a heap and seeing LOTS of lock / unlock activity, though nothing exclusive on the table, just Schema-Shared (Metadata). Will start testing with a clustered index and using a real field vs just a variable. I will update soon with the test code as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Update Locks are taken prior to finding any rows to update, which are converted to Exclusive upon finding something to update. But it seems that in this case, the row(s) that match the WHERE clause count as "found" so it does end up taking an Exclusive lock. I found no evidence of any special optimization when not specifying any real field to update. The SELECT also did some locking, but it was all Shared, so less impacting to other processes. So we (you, me, and Dan) are all in agreement that this should be a SELECT. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have done additional testing and confirmed that there is no logging at all in this variable-only update, or even an UPDATE that affects 0 rows. I have updated the answer with that info. I have also done more testing related to locking and it is too varied/complex to post here so I will write an article about it, but there is an `IX` lock taken on the table, `U` taken on each row which is released if no update or converted to `X` if it will update. And as I stated, when using `SNAPSHOT` isolation level, a fraction of the locks are taken. Still, the `SELECT` is best in all cases.